# Connection Refused Error in Cloud Foundry Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have been facing issue with deploying a spring boot application in Pivotal Cloud Web Foundry. I keep getting this error:

```
 2018-01-29T22:18:50.84-0500 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make HTTP request to '/' on port 8080: connection refused
 2018-01-29T22:18:50.84-0500 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 15s: health check never passed.
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.stargate.transferfund</groupId>
<artifactId>TransferFund</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>TransferFund</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <startClass>org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication</startClass>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JMS related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Controller class

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity sayHello() {
    return new ResponseEntity("Hello world", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
}
```

> Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TransferFundApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TransferFundApplication.class, args);
}

/**
 * Used when run as WAR
 */
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(TransferFundApplication.class);
}
}
```

> manifest.yml

```
---
applications:
- name: target
  path: target/TransferFund-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  health-check-type: http
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
```

It looks like the port 8080 is not detected for some reasons. I have tried changing the health-check-type to process and port. When I change it to process it works but the endpoints are not longer accessible. Need some help in solving the issue

Comment: A couple quick notes:  1.) Don't point to the master branch of the buildpack as it can change/break.  You always want to use a stable release or the buildpack included with your PCF platform.  2.) Set the health check to port.  It'll be easier to debug because all the app needs to do is start up successfully to pass that health check.  Once you've done step #1 & #2, get a full set of logs from the minute you `cf push` to the moment the app crashes and post them here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after adding the following dependency of actuator :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also add the following to the manifest.yml :

```
health-check-http-endpoint: /info
health-check-type: http
```

I think this should solve the problem.